# How to find unique pairs and print to list from list of strings?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a a function that will take a string, break the entire string down into a list (or 2, or maybe even a dictionary) I honestly don't know here.

What the function needs to do is read the list from left to right, then read it again left to right at the index+1 position, and then make a new list adding to each iteration.

From there it needs to count each of these new pairs and then return only pairs with 2 or more occurrences.

For example:

```
This is Bob
This is Steve
Hi I'm John
```

From that list it should make a new list with this output:
`{This is: 2} {is Bob : 1} {Bob This : 1} {is Steve : 1} {Steve Hi : 1} {Hi I'm : 1} {I'm John : 1}`

Then cut all the 1's and only leave me with `{This is : 2}` because it is the only one that occurs more than once.

This is what I have so far in terms of code:

```
import re

##Use Regex to strip numbers, newlines, and special characters from str
def wordCleanUp(cleanUp):
    cleanUpLower = cleanUp.lower()
    wordCleanUp1 = cleanUpLower.strip()
    wordCleanUp2 = re.sub("\d+", "", wordCleanUp1)
    wordCleanUp3 = re.sub(pattern="[^\w\s]", repl="", string=wordCleanUp2)
    wordCleanUp = wordCleanUp3.split()
    return wordCleanUp

def wordPairs(fileName):
    fileContent = open(fileName, 'r')
    uniquePairStr = fileContent.split()
    uniquePairList = wordCleanUp(uniquePairStr)

def main():
    fileName = input("Enter the name of file with extension, e.g. example.txt: ")

    wordPairs(fileName)


main()
```

As you can see, I don't even have code to troubleshoot here, everything listed works for all the other functions I am currently using.  The only problem I have is that I have no idea how to complete the code in my `wordPairs` function.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andrej, make's it a bit more readable

Comment: What's the resulting value for `uniquePairList`? Is it what you expected to get?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that shows the problem.

Comment: "Read the list from left to right, then read it again at the index+1 position" - this doesn't sound too hard, what happened when you tried to do this?

Comment: @Prune Unfortunately the person who edited my post first deleted the last paragraph on accident.  I was asking for resources that might show me how to do what I listed above.  I'm not looking for code correction, or trouble shooting.  Just resources so I can learn it myself.  Google isn't too great at getting me the answers I need when it's about coding.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Asking for resource references is specifically listed as off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Generate bigrams from your text and count occurrences:

```
import collections

# text <- open('example.txt').read()
words = text.split()
bigrams = map(' '.join, zip(words, words[1:]))
counter = collections.Counter(bigrams)
```

```
>>> dict(counter)
{'This is': 2,
 'is Bob': 1,
 'Bob This': 1,
 'is Steve': 1,
 'Steve Hi': 1,
 "Hi I'm": 1,
 "I'm John": 1}
```

Comment: Not allowed to, this is for a class assignment.  If the instructor has to install extra software it disqualifies.  I can import any and all libraries, but numpy, conda, etc are all not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the problem.  Read the file into `fileContent` just as you've done, break it into words, stripping out all the white space.  Now, make your word pairs by `zip`ping the list with a shifted version of itself:

```
pairs = zip(wordList, wordList[1:])
```

Now simply count pairs:

```
from collections import Counter
pair_count = Counter(pairs)
multiple = [(key, val) for key, val in Counter.items() if val > 1]
```

Note that I've left the word pairs as tuples; if you want strings, you can `' '.join()` them at any point.

Comment: Is it seriously that easy?!?!  Dude you're a godsend.  But seriously though, I would love to see a resource to learn a bit more about this.  Also it doesn't have to be strings so long as I can print it in a single column, with the count in the next column.

Comment: Yes, it's that easy.  Again, this is not a reference resource.  Depending on what you mean by "learn a bit more", you may want to get into Natural Language Processing (NLP) and the associated packages.  You have a lot of research and learning to enjoy from here.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.